# Why GET/POST/PUT request taking too long?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

I have conducted performance testing on a e-commerce website and trying find some scaling issue using Azure logs. I observed that CPU and Network usage were stable but still the response time is high. So I dig deep and found few request which taking too long to complete. For example: " GET/api/invoices/{orderId}" is taking about 882ms to complete. below a screenshot is provided:
[image]

As you can see some of the request taking long time. So is this because of the slow database queries or can i indicate based on this result? Thanks!

Comment: If your CPU/mem is stable it means that the CPU is waiting for something, you need to check IOs: your disk, your database, partner APIs etc. and monitor it for the period of time. There are too little information to answer your question, you need to publish the code or architecture schemas to identify bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

If you use application insight you can navigate to *Performance*

[image]

and there you can choose the requests that take to long and see where you have the biggest performance issue on this specific request( database, key-vault, azure table etc)
like here:
[image]